# Deploy Rails 5 on Heroku download yarn gets stuck with message "Timed out running buildpack Ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, heroku-ci

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 5 application on Heroku.
It comes to the `Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install` step,
then it seems to get stuck for about 30 minutes.  Then it shows `Timed out running buildpack Ruby` and process is killed by SIGTERM

```
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
-----> Timed out running buildpack Ruby
!
!     SIGTERM
!
!     Push failed
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following buildpack: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

Create a `Aptfile` with the content `yarn`.